# Basics of file formats

Tags: file, format

I know that it might sound silly but, while working on project at some time I feel the need of knowing the very basics of file formats.

I know every thing is stored in binary 1-0 in hard disk and can get an input stream of that.

But now what if

1. I don't know the format of file now how to decide it by input stream
2. I know its format now what part of the input stream represent different portions of file
   for eg. take a jpeg file that red background now what part of stream represent this information.

I need urgent help(any type links to blog e-books) will be highly appreciable.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [List of file signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) and [Magic number (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)
2. Why do you need to operate on such a low level like input streams? Use a library to get you the information needed on the given file. And btw your jpeg example is a bad one. jpeg is a pixel based image format which has no such thing like "background". That "background" exists only because the user interpretes the red pixels as background.

Comment: Beacuse i want to make my own format for file and as i am very much a newbie I didn't have any other eg to make my point.